# Trig functions in css transform?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to put some circles around a larger circle at specific angles using transform: translate and cos and sin functions. It doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure why.

```css
.ctr_btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  display: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
.out_btn {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;

  //this is the part I'm concerned about.
  transform: translateX(calc(2rem * cos(var(--angle)))) translateY(calc(2rem * sin(var(--angle))));
}
```

```html
  <div class="Nav">
    <div class="ctr_btn">
      maincircle
      <div class="out_btn" style="--angle:15deg">1</div>
      <div class="out_btn" style="--angle:30deg">2</div>
      <div class="out_btn" style="--angle:45deg">3</div>
      <div class="out_btn" style="--angle:60deg">4</div>
      <div class="out_btn" style="--angle:75deg">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See this snippet:

https://codepen.io/spencerbug/pen/PvwaWQ

Thank you!

Comment: `cos` and `sin` are sass functions. Those would be evaluated when compiling your sass file to write your CSS. While CSS just recently added support for `cos` and `sin` (and a few other trig methods), it's a bit aways before they're available in browsers. As such, you'll need to create classes based on the various `angles` you've defined in your `style` attributes and leverage sass to easily generate the CSS needed for your design.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I forgot about the whole preprocessor thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the same result with a little trick. Just rotate the angle that you want, translate it by the radius length, and counter rotate by the same angle. This way, the result is the same, and you don't need trig functions.

```css
.ctr_btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  display: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  margin: 100px;
}
.out_btn {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;

 
  transform:  rotate(var(--angle)) translate(10em) rotate(calc(-1 * var(--angle)));
}
```

```html
<div class="Nav">
    <div class="ctr_btn">
      maincircle
      <div class="out_btn" style="--angle:15deg">1</div>
      <div class="out_btn" style="--angle:30deg">2</div>
      <div class="out_btn" style="--angle:45deg">3</div>
      <div class="out_btn" style="--angle:60deg">4</div>
      <div class="out_btn" style="--angle:75deg">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I ended up doing. I used sass to generate a class for every angle 0-359. Now I can rotate around with that

Comment: This is incredibly brilliant, just wanna point this out. It also demonstrates the fact that when you use `rotate()`, the `x` and `y` axes are also rotated, which is incredibly handy knowledge I didn't have before.

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with Firefox 108 and Safari 15.4 (and experimentally in Chrome 111 and Edge 111), the trigonometric `cos()` and `sin()` CSS functions are now supported (at < 18% browser coverage for either function, pls see [this reference](https://caniuse.com/?search=sin()) for example).

For the full list of trigonometric functions, please see the [W3C documentation](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-values/#trig-funcs).

Comment: Also supported: `tan()`, `asin()`, `acos()`, `atan()`, `atan2()`. Browser coverage is now ~61%. See this page for example usage: https://web.dev/css-trig-functions/